# How do I float left the entire div instead of just the size of image?

Tags: html, css

```css
div.comment {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
}

.type {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment">
  <p class="name"><a href="">Bob</a></p>
  <img src="http://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png" />
  <p class="type">Regular User</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
  <p><a href="">Reply</a></p>
</div>
```

As you can see it currently goes over my contents. Anyway to alter this to get what I want?   /

Comment: it will be better if you redo the html structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap everything after the image into an own `div`, and apply `display: inline-block;` to both the image and that new `div` (erase the float setting). Apply `width` settings so that both add up to max. 100% (better a bit less):

```css
div.comment {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.type {
  color: green;
}

.textcontainer {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 85%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment">
  <p class="name"><a href="">Bob</a></p>
  <img src="http://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png" />
  <div class="textcontainer">
    <p class="type">Regular User</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p><a href="">Reply</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With flexbox and a few container `div`s, you can achieve this layout pretty easily, and without the use of `float`.

```css
.card {
  display: flex;
}

.post-content {
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.post-content p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.card img {
  width: 192px;
  height: 192px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="left-column">
    <img src="http://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png">    
  </div>
  <div class="post-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, voluptatibus! Voluptate, ab praesentium</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea eligendi beatae consequatur, suscipit corporis! Perspiciatis distinctio neque nulla minus in cum, eligendi totam ab facilis! Reiciendis quae hic impedit obcaecati!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea eligendi beatae consequatur, suscipit corporis! Perspiciatis distinctio neque nulla minus in cum, eligendi totam ab facilis! Reiciendis quae hic impedit obcaecati!</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea eligendi beatae consequatur, suscipit corporis! Perspiciatis distinctio neque nulla minus in cum, eligendi totam ab facilis! Reiciendis quae hic impedit obcaecati!</p>    
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/antibland/m8vhgx3w/9/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with some flex values and some extra divs. Feel free to play around with values and formats to change image size, margins etc. Hope this helps.

```css
    .container{
        display: flex;
    }
    .comment {
            background: yellow;
            border: 1px solid #999;
            padding: 1em;
            margin-bottom: 1em;
            margin-left: 20px;
            flex: 1;
    }

    .user{
        flex: 0 0 5%;
    }

    .user p{
        text-align: center;
    }

    img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    }

    .type {
    color: green;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="user">
        <img src="http://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png" />
        <p class="name"><a href="">Bob</a></p>
        <p class="type">Regular User</p>
    </div>
    <div class="comment">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum</p>
        <p><a href="">Reply</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.comment_content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.comment_text {
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 80%;
}

.comment_image {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 20%;
}

.comment_image img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
}

.name {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.type {
  color: green;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment_content">
  <div class="comment_image">
      <img src="http://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png" />
      <p class="name"><a href="">Bob</a></p>
      <p class="type">Regular User</p>
  </div>
  <div class="comment_text">
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
      </p>
      <p><a href="">Reply</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```